# Android calendar view set current date always selected

Tags: android, calendarview

I am using calendar view in my app. Up to now I have made selection of dates I want using new DayViewDecorator(). But the problem is that I want to make the current date should always appear with red background(or any certain color/resource). If user selects another day, current day's background will be red(keep unchanged).

My code snippet is

```
dayViewDecorator = new DayViewDecorator() {
      Drawable bg=getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.ic_sample);
      @Override
      public boolean shouldDecorate(CalendarDay calendarDay) {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String formattedCalenderDate = dateFormat.format(calendarDay.getDate().getTime());
          if(formattedCalenderDate.endsWith(currentDate))
            bg=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.lyk_share);
        if (allOrganizerActivityDates.contains(formattedCalenderDate)){
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      }

      @Override
      public void decorate(DayViewFacade dayViewFacade) {
        dayViewFacade.setBackgroundDrawable(bg);
      }
    };
calendarView.addDecorator(dayViewDecorator);
```

Please help me out. Any help will be appreciated.